# Running an external program before exiting java sometime fails

Tags: java, windows, uac

I have a java program, running on Windows XP through 10 systems, that calls a program (Mover.exe) before it exits.  What I want to happen is after the java program exits Mover.exe should overwrite, and thus update, the java program with downloaded files.

I am using `new ProcessBuilder(progname, options).directory(tempDir).start();`
to call Mover.exe but it only works intermittently.

Of course some of the systems running the program have UAC enabled, some don't, and it seems the UAC systems are the ones causing the hassle.  I don't know if it is the delay from the Elevation request or an issue with timing/file locks.

Has anyone dealt with trying to create their own updater with java or seen a good guide about dealing with these type of issues?

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I solved similar problem by generating `.cmd` batch which waits couple of seconds and then runs the tool (`Mover.exe` in your case).

More beautiful solution is, having a "launcher" application which just

- starts your app,
- runs `Mover.exe` if somehow signaled (like special exitCode),
- (almost) never needs to be updated itself

Then you must make sure that your app is only started via this launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Plug-and-play has one form in java: java **SPI** (Service Providing Interface).

- **api.jar** with `package x.y.z; public interface Pluggable { void exec(String[] args); }`.
- **mainapp.jar**: the tiny application that inspects the plugin jars on the class path by interface, starts the latest, maybe deletes the oldest.
- **plugin12.jar** with `package u.v.w; public class Plugin12 extends Pluggable { ... }` and text file `META-INF/services/x.y.z.Pluggable` with a line `u.v.w.App12`.
- **plugin13.jar** with `package u.v.w; public class Plugin13 extends Pluggable { ... }` and text file `META-INF/services/x.y.z.Pluggable` with a line `u.v.w.App13`.

The classpath may be a collective directory with jars.

```
ServiceLoader<Pluggable> loader = ServiceLoader .load(Pluggable.class);
Iterator<Pluggable> iter = loader.iterator();
... pick by latest class name or such
pluggable.exec(args);
```

Admittedly this is works differently but does not rely on system specifics (Linux, any Windows).